# No more than 3 is allowed or are allowed?

Tags: verbs, verb-agreement

I am wondering which is correct, is or are? Also 2 is allowed or are allowed?

Comment: More than two are not allowed...sounds better.

Comment: @RamPillai But three ***is*** allowed according to the title.

Comment: @RamPillai If no more than three are allowed then zero, one, two or three are allowed but not four. If your workplace says "No more than three sick days can be taken without a medical certificate" employees who take no days, one day, two days or three days off sick do not need a medical certificate but anyone taking four or more does. To answer the question you need 'are' because the numbers prohibited are plural.

Comment: Three *is* a number. Three examples *are* needed. Three sick days are allowed without a certificate. Three is the maximum number of sick days which may be taken without a certificate.

Comment: Appreciate the correction @BoldBen, Peter and Jim. :)